# Scaling with rotating image using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have using scaling and rotation of images using mouse dragging separately. but i need to combine both the operations.

Please refer jsfiddle files for your understanding.

Scaling - http://jsfiddle.net/QqwKR/74/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown = false;


    var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var resizerRadius = 8;
    var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
    var draggingResizer = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var imageX = 50;
    var imageY = 50;
    var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
    var draggingImage = false;
    var startX;
    var startY;



    var img = new Image();
img.onload = function (){
        imageWidth = img.width;
        imageHeight = img.height;
        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;
    draw(true, false);}

    img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";


    function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {

        // clear the canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // draw the image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);

        // optionally draw the draggable anchors
        if (withAnchors) {
            drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
            drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
            drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
        }

        // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
        if (withBorders) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
            ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
            ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    }

    function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }

    function anchorHitTest(x, y) {

        var dx, dy;

        // top-left
        dx = x - imageX;
        dy = y - imageY;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (0);
        }
        // top-right
        dx = x - imageRight;
        dy = y - imageY;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (1);
        }
        // bottom-right
        dx = x - imageRight;
        dy = y - imageBottom;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (2);
        }
        // bottom-left
        dx = x - imageX;
        dy = y - imageBottom;
        if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
            return (3);
        }
        return (-1);

    }


    function hitImage(x, y) {
        return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e) {
        startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
        draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e) {
        draggingResizer = -1;
        draggingImage = false;
        draw(true, false);
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e) {
        handleMouseUp(e);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e) {

        if (draggingResizer > -1) {

            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // resize the image
            switch (draggingResizer) {
                case 0:
                    //top-left
                    imageX = mouseX;
                    imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                    imageY = mouseY;
                    imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //top-right
                    imageY = mouseY;
                    imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                    imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //bottom-right
                    imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                    imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //bottom-left
                    imageX = mouseX;
                    imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                    imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                    break;
            }

            // enforce minimum dimensions of 25x25
            if (imageWidth < 25) {
                imageWidth = 25;
            }
            if (imageHeight < 25) {
                imageHeight = 25;
            }

            // set the image right and bottom
            imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
            imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

            // redraw the image with resizing anchors
            draw(true, true);

        } else if (draggingImage) {

            imageClick = false;

           mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
            var dx = mouseX - startX;
            var dy = mouseY - startY;
            imageX += dx;
            imageY += dy;
            imageRight += dx;
            imageBottom += dy;
            // reset the startXY for next time
            startX = mouseX;
            startY = mouseY;

            // redraw the image with border
            draw(false, true);

        }


    }


    $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
        handleMouseDown(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
        handleMouseUp(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
        handleMouseOut(e);
    });
```

Rotating - http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QqwKR/

```
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;


    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown = false;


    var cx = canvas.width / 2;
    var cy = canvas.height / 2;
    var w;
    var h;
    var r = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        w = img.width / 2;
        h = img.height / 2;
        draw();
    }
    img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";


    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawRotationHandle(true);
        drawRect();
    }

    function drawRect() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx, cy);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, -w / 2, -h / 2, w, h);
        //    ctx.fillStyle="yellow";
        //    ctx.fillRect(-w/2,-h/2,w,h);
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawRotationHandle(withFill) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx, cy);
        ctx.rotate(r);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, -1);
        ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, -1);
        ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, -7);
        ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 30, -7);
        ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 30, 7);
        ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, 7);
        ctx.lineTo(w / 2 + 20, 1);
        ctx.lineTo(0, 1);
        ctx.closePath();
        if (withFill) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }



    function handleMouseDown(e) {
        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        drawRotationHandle(false);
        isDown = ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY);
        console.log(isDown);
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e) {
        isDown = false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e) {
        isDown = false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        if (!isDown) {
            return;
        }

        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        var dx = mouseX - cx;
        var dy = mouseY - cy;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        r = angle;
        draw();
    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
        handleMouseDown(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
        handleMouseUp(e);
    });
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
        handleMouseOut(e);
    })

;
```

I need to work scaling **with** rotation of image. ie) Four anchor points with rotating handle

Comment: Update your question with a real question please, it's not clear what exactly it is you need help with.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?